# Is a surjective finite morphism always a branched covering?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, covering-spaces

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a surjective finite morphism of schemes over $\mathbb{C}$. We know $f$ must be quasi-finite, i.e., its fibers are finite. We also know the cardinality of the finite fiber above a generic point $y$ of $Y$ is the same, which is the degree of $f$.

**My questions are:**

Is $f$ always a branched covering? If not, what's a counter-example?

What if we further require that $f$ is an étale morphism?

**Edit:**
I'm not sure if it always makes sense to talk about branched coverings in the full category of schemes over $\mathbb{C}$. We can take the schemes to be algebraic varieties for now. By a branched covering $f:X \to Y$, I mean a morphism $f:X \to Y$ such that it's indeed a covering map over an open $V \subset Y$.

Comment: What is your definition of branched covering?

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm not sure whether it makes sense to talk about branched coverings in the category of schemes. I guess I want a branched covering $f: X \to Y$ of algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ to be a covering over an open $V \subset Y$.

Comment: Quick comment: you know that since we are in characteristic $0$ that $f$ is generically smooth, and since $f$ is finite, it is then generically etale. Thus, $f$ is generically finite etale.